# SSPI Schannel API returns undocumented value of 0xAE06 or CALG_ECDH_EPHEM

Tags: ssl, winapi, sspi, schannel

I am using the following code to query current TLS connection:

```
SecPkgContext_ConnectionInfo data;
QueryContextAttributes(&myHandle, SECPKG_ATTR_CONNECTION_INFO, &data);
```

It returns correct structure with all the fields:

```
typedef struct _SecPkgContext_ConnectionInfo {
  DWORD  dwProtocol;
  ALG_ID aiCipher;
  DWORD  dwCipherStrength;
  ALG_ID aiHash;
  DWORD  dwHashStrength;
  ALG_ID aiExch;
  DWORD  dwExchStrength;
} SecPkgContext_ConnectionInfo, *PSecPkgContext_ConnectionInfo;
```

as per MSDN documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/schannel/ns-schannel-secpkgcontext_connectioninfo

However, the field `aiExch` has value of 0xAE06 which I guess (from wincrypt.h file) is defined as `CALG_ECDH_EPHEM`, but documentation only mention two possible values:

```
CALG_RSA_KEYX 0xA400   // RSA key exchange
CALG_DH_EPHEM 0xAA02   // Diffie-Hellman key exchange.
```

Now the questions:

1. What is the meaning of 0xAE06 / CALG_ECDH_EPHEM?
2. What other values the field `aiExch` can have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ALG_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/alg-id):

> CALG_ECDH_EPHEM |  0x0000ae06 |  Ephemeral elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm.
>
> > [!Note]
> >     This algorithm is supported only through 
> >     Cryptography API: Next Generation
>
> Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP: This algorithm is not supported.

I can't tell you what else might show up.